# Trying to retrieve data in JS that is in the function to be used outside of the function

Tags: javascript

So I've read quite a few articles on the asyn nature of JS, so I'm kind of understanding what I'm doing wrong but I still don't understand how callbacks fix the asyn nature to allow you to retrieve a result. In my code, I am using the YouTube Data API to retrieve the video of movies that I am embedding in my project. I can get the video to console login to my function but I need that videoId outside of the function. How would I use a callback to extract that data?

Here is my code:

```
// Blank Variable to store videoId
var idForMovie = "";

async function getMovieTrailer() {
    let resultAll = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
    let searchResults = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=" + encodeURIComponent(`${movieArray[k].Title} Trailer`)
     + "&key=" + apiKey);
    let search = await searchResults.json();
    resultAll.push(search);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < resultAll.length; i++) {
      var {items} = resultAll[i]; //object destructuring
      console.log(items);
        for (var j = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var {videoId} = items[i].id; //object destructuring
        console.log(videoId);
        idForMovie = videoId;
        }
      }
    //console.log(searchItems);
    return idForMovie;
}
getMovieTrailer();
console.log(idForMovie);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks do not resolve that behaviour, if you do:

```
let variable;
object.onevent = (event) => variable = event
console.log(variable) // undefined
```

It's the same of doing:

```
let variable;
promise.then(result => variable = result)
console.log(variable) //undefined
```

This happens because the variable declaration and the `console.log` are placed in queue of the EventLoop synchronously hence executed sequentially, immediately, while both the callback mechanism and the promise mechanism are deferred.

If you want to do something  relative to a global/upper-scoped variable, and you know that that variable will be changed as a consequence of an asynchronous task, you must necessarily do that inside the callback if you are using callbacks, or in the `then()` callback of a promise.
Consider two more things:

1. A callback based task, can easily be converted in Promise based:

```
object.onevent = (event) => // do something
```

becomes:

```
const promise = new Promise( resolve => object.onevent = resolve )
promise.then( event => // do something )
```

1. An `async` function as that one in your example, is just a function that returns a `Promise`, based on JavaScript generators, so inside of it it "looks" synchronous, but it all happens asynchronously:

```
const asynchronousFn = async () => {
const something = await somethingAsync()
doSomethingSynchronous()
return something
}
```

is the same of:

```
const asynchronousFn = () => somethingAsync().then(something => {
doSomethingSynchronous()
return something
})
```

The only real reason why `Promises` and then `async/await` were introduced in ECMA was to avoid *Callbacks Hell* phenomenum.

There are patterns that help you to manage this kind of scenarios, one of this is the Observable Pattern, and there are tools that help us doing that *( observables )* : https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

But this is all another matter!

***NOTE:*** There is an active stage4 proposal to introduce ES modules that are totally asynchronous. This means that you will be able to do something like:

```
let variable;
const somethingThatChangesVariableAsynchronously = async () => variable = "Something"
const somethingThatUsesVariable = () => console.log(variable)
await somethingThatChangesVariableAsynchronously()
somethingThatUsesVariable() // Something
```

This means that the whole module is asynchronous but you can write a sort of synchronous code inside of it as you do inside async functions.
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait your `getMovieTrailer()` to return, then assign `idForMovie` to the returned value. For this you will need another `async` function, because `await` is only available within `async` functions

```
// Blank Variable to store videoId
var idForMovie = "";

async function getMovieTrailer() {
    let resultAll = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
    let searchResults = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=" + encodeURIComponent(`${movieArray[k].Title} Trailer`)
     + "&key=" + apiKey);
    let search = await searchResults.json();
    resultAll.push(search);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < resultAll.length; i++) {
      var {items} = resultAll[i]; //object destructuring
      console.log(items);
        for (var j = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var {videoId} = items[i].id; //object destructuring
        console.log(videoId);
        idForMovie = videoId;
        }
      }
    //console.log(searchItems);
    return idForMovie;
}

async function nextFunction() {
    idForMovie = await getMovieTrailer();
    console.log(idForMovie);
}
```

Comment: So this brings a lot of clarity to how a callback works. I just call the getMovieTrailer() function right before  nextFunction. Unfortunately it's still not working but this helps!

Comment: 'Unfortunately it's still not working but this helps! '. Just call the function and it works. `nextFunction()`. Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if it is solves your problem